# How do I turn a page into template on SharePoint Online ?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, team-sites

Hope you are well;

I would like to know how I can turn a page into a template on SharePoint online. The reason for this is because I want to use on different site collections and on team sites. is possible for me to deploy this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to Page Layout. You can include web part zones, predefined web parts, content areas and other content in a Page Layout, then bind it to a content type.

I'd personally do it like this

1. create the page layout using SharePoint Designer
2. download it
3. create PowerShell script that uploads the Page Layout to Site Collection
4. and creates and binds to Content Type, or just binds to existing Content Type.

Comment: I just want to save a page as template is possible for me

Comment: Unfortunately not possible just like that.

Comment: why is not possible.

Comment: There just isn't such functionality in SharePoint to create a page, then save it as template for later use. You only can save a team site as template, but that's different thing altogether.